# combine pandas apply results as multiple columns in a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Summary**

Suppose that you `apply` a `function` to a groupby object, so that every `g.apply` for every `g` in the `df.groupby(...)` gives you a series/dataframe. How do I combine these results into a single dataframe, but with the group names as columns?

**Details**

I have a dataframe `event_df` that looks like this:

```
index   event   note   time
0       on      C      0.5
1       on      D      0.75
2       off     C      1.0
...
```

I want to create a sampling of the `event` for every `note`, and the sampling is done at times as given by `t_df`:

```
index    t
0        0
1        0.5
2        1.0
...
```

So that I'd get something like this.

```
t        C         D        
0        off       off
0.5      on        off
1.0      off       on
...
```

**What I've done so far:**

```
def get_t_note_series(notedata_row, t_arr):
   """Return the time index in the sampling that corresponds to the event."""
   t_idx = np.argwhere(t_arr >= notedata_row['time']).flatten()[0]
   return t_idx

def get_t_for_gb(group, **kwargs):
   t_idxs = group.apply(get_t_note_series, args=(t_arr,), axis=1)
   t_idxs.rename('t_arr_idx', inplace=True)
   group_with_t = pd.concat([group, t_idxs], axis=1).set_index('t_arr_idx')
   print(group_with_t)
   return group_with_t


t_arr = np.arange(0,10,0.5)
t_df = pd.DataFrame({'t': t_arr}).rename_axis('t_arr_idx')
gb = event_df.groupby('note')
gb.apply(get_t_for_gb, **kwargs)
```

So what I get is a number of dataframes for each note, all of the same size (same as t_df):

```
t     event
0     on
0.5   off
...

t     event
0     off
0.5   on
...
```

How do I go from here to my desired dataframe, with each group corresponding to a column in a new dataframe, and the index being `t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh so I found it! All I had to do was to `unstack` the groupby results. Going back to generating the groupby result:

```
def get_t_note_series(notedata_row, t_arr):
   """Return the time index in the sampling that corresponds to the event."""
   t_idx = np.argwhere(t_arr >= notedata_row['time']).flatten()[0]
   return t_idx

def get_t_for_gb(group, **kwargs):
   t_idxs = group.apply(get_t_note_series, args=(t_arr,), axis=1)
   t_idxs.rename('t_arr_idx', inplace=True)
   group_with_t = pd.concat([group, t_idxs], axis=1).set_index('t_arr_idx')
   ## print(group_with_t) ## unnecessary!
   return group_with_t


t_arr = np.arange(0,10,0.5)
t_df = pd.DataFrame({'t': t_arr}).rename_axis('t_arr_idx')
gb = event_df.groupby('note')
result = gb.apply(get_t_for_gb, **kwargs)
```

At this point, `result` is a dataframe with `note` as an index:

```
>> print(result)

          event
note  t
C     0    off
      0.5  on
      1.0  off
....
D     0    off
      0.5  off
      1.0  on
....
```

Doing `result = result.unstack('note')` does the trick:

```
>> result = result.unstack('note')
>> print(result)

         event
note     C      D
t
0        off    off
0.5      on     on
1.0      off    off
....
D     0    off
      0.5  off
      1.0  on
....
```

Comment: better `result = result['event'].unstack(0)`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: sorry, I didn't take into account below, that you rescale your `time` column and can't present a whole solution now because I have to leave, but I think, you could do the rescaling by using `pandas.merge_asof` with your two dataframes to get the nearest "rescaled" time and from the merged dataframe you could try the code below. I hope this is, what you wanted.

```
import pandas as pd
import io 

sio= io.StringIO("""index   event   note   time
0       on      C      0.5
1       on      D      0.75
2       off     C      1.0""")
df= pd.read_csv(sio, sep='\s+', index_col=0)

df.groupby(['time', 'note']).agg({'event': 'first'}).unstack(-1).fillna('off')
```

Take the first row in each time-note group by `agg({'event': 'first'})`, then use the `note`-index column and transpose it, so the `note` values become columns. Then at the end fill all cells, for which no datapoints could be found with 'off' by `fillna`.

This outputs:

```
Out[28]: 
     event     
note     C    D
time           
0.50    on  off
0.75   off   on
1.00   off  off
```

You might also want to try `min` or `max` in case on/off is not unambiguous for a combination of time/note (if there are more rows for the same time/note where some have on and some have off) and you prefer one of these values (say if there is one on, then no matter how many offs are there, you want an on etc.). If you want something like a mayority-vote, I would suggest to add a mayority vote column in the aggregated dataframe (before the `unstack()`).

Comment: I think I've gotten all my desired columns as mentioned in my original post. The only problem is I don't know how to put all the results together as multiple columns in a single dataframe. One option could be to do a `for n, g in gb.groups:   g.apply(...)` and then create a list of columns for concatenation, but I wonder if there's an easier way that doesn't require iterative over the groups.

Comment: Anyway I found the answer to my question, but this was still a good answer on how to go from the original dataframe to a similar end result. Thanks a lot!